# testing value in NEO4j

Tags: if-statement, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get around IF queries in NEO4J.

Something like (if I could use  IF):

```
MATCH (n:person)<-[r:aetei]-(m:person)    
IF m.ai >= 2
RETURN n, m, r
```

with `aetei` being a relationship between persons, and `ai` an attribute (obviously).

I tried some queries with foreach, but without results as I don't understand what to put after the | and how to get into the return.
I've seen some examples with queries in the RETURN ... is that possible ?
greetings

I tried several solutions like FOREACH or CASE, but nothing worked. I guess I'm too fresh on NEO4J to really get what 'im doing.
Should i install apoc ?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to return a particular record if `m.ai > 2`?

Comment: `WHERE` to add conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for `WHERE`:

```
MATCH (n:person)<-[r:aetei]-(m:person)
WHERE m.ai >= 2 
RETURN n, m, r
```